# Show that the set is a closure of $U_j$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Omega$ be an open and nonempty set and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let's define a set $U_j=\{x\in\Omega:\Vert x\Vert<j \wedge dist(x,bd(\Omega))<\frac{1}{j}\}$.
We observe that $U_j$ is open.

Now let's define $\overline{U_j}=\{x\in\Omega:\Vert x\Vert\leq j \wedge dist(x,bd(\Omega))\leq\frac{1}{j}\}$.

I need to show that this is the closure of $U_j$.  It's quite obvious that $U_j \subset \overline{U_j}$. It is a closed set, because the complementary set is open. But I don't know how to show that this is the correct set.

Comment: Use one of the properties of the closure, e.g. that $cl(Y)$ is the smallest closed set, containing $Y$. More concrete: for any closed set $X$ with $U_j \subseteq X$, show that $\overline{U}_j \subseteq X$.

Comment: Could you give me more clues? I don't see how I should show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the following.

The claim is false. For a counterexample put $n=2$, $\Omega$ be an open disk with the center at the origin and radius $2$, and $j=1$. Then $\Omega_1=\varnothing$, but $\overline{\Omega_1}$ is a circle with the center at the origin and radius $1$.